# Atomikos with Spring Boot gives atomikos.icatch.SysException: No Assembler Service found - please make sure that the right jars are in your class path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, atomikos, 2phase-commit

I am trying to use Atomikos with Spring Boot to try a distributed transaction across two databases.  I have followed the documentation but no matter what I do I get the error below:

`com.atomikos.icatch.SysException: No Assembler Service found - please make sure that the right jars are in your class path`

I have referenced spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos in maven and then tried to use UserTransactionManagerImp as documented.  I even tried using UserTransactionManager, init() it and then assign it to TransactionManager.  But none of the variations worked either.  It always fails on UserTransactionManager line with above error.  Can someone please advise on what configuration mistake am I doing?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a maven issue. The required Atomikos-transactions.jar did not get pulled/saved in my "m2" folder of my machine - so, the runtime couldn't load AssemblerImp class which resulted in this error. The error does not indicate which jar file is missing, just that Assembler service is not found. Hope this helps someone that runs into the same issue.